# trigger.io iOS in-app purchase issue: "In-app payment failed: Cannot connect to itunes store"

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, trigger.io

I've developed an app in trigger.io and submitted to app store successfully. the app is reviewed and added to the store. Now I'm trying to add in-app purchase feature for my app, but I'm not sure at which point i could test in-app purchase. current steps I did:

1. upload app for review
2. create a product in itunes connect
3. app is approved

at this point I'm trying to test purchase with the payments module in trigger.io with this code:

```
forge.payments.purchaseProduct("Product1", paymentSuccess, paymentError);
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
"In-app payment failed: Cannot connect to itunes store"
```

What am I doing wrong? should I create a new version, add my product to this version and upload for reviewal again to be able to test it, which seems absurd to submit an app without working functions.

For the record, I'm using developer certificate and provisioning profile to test my app, naturally, and I've created a test user in itunes connect which I'm using to test the purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. the problem was, I was using a distribution certificate & provisioning profile. I should've been using development certificate & provisioning profile to test in-app payments.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, the problem was expired contracts in itunesconnect.
[image]